# Connecting to POP3 server gives Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection issue

Tags: java, ssl, jakarta-mail, pop3

Im trying to connect to the POP3 server using the [Java API](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/com/sun/mail/pop3/package-summary.html) with no SSL.

I have set following properties;

```
mail.pop3.host :- pop.gmx.com
mail.pop3.password:-XXXX
 mail.pop3.user:-XXXX
mail.pop3.port:- 110
```

But I'm getting the following issue:

```
javax.mail.MessagingException: Connect failed;
  nested exception is:
    javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Unrecognized SSL message, plaintext connection?
    at com.sun.mail.pop3.POP3Store.protocolConnect(POP3Store.java:148)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:275)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:156)
    at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
```

What property did I miss?

Comment: As far as I know, GMX only does support SSL for remote connection. (at least the German GMX)

https://translate.google.de/translate?hl=de&sl=auto&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gmx.net%2Fe-mail-made-in-germany%2Fssl

Comment: I configure according to this link. http://email.about.com/od/gmxmailtips/f/GMX_Mail_POP3_Server_Settings.htm .  There they say they support non ssl too?

Comment: You are citing a non-official link from 2012. Maybe you should use SSL ;)

Answer (score 0):

The page you cite clearly says:

```
POP port: 995 (alternative: 110)
TLS/SSL required: yes (if you use port 110: no)
```

IOW port 110 is a plaintext port. So use 995 like it says. Or plaintext.

Comment: What do you mean by palintext? I try to connect to port 110 with no ssl, then why i get that error?

Comment: You've set SSL somewhere. Look again.